# Disc Rotor Alignment Mavic Crosstrail

Tags: maintenance, hub

I have a disc rotor alignment question you maybe can help me with.

I have a Canyon Nerve AL+ 8.0 that's been working nice until the front wheel got stuck on the brake. First I thought it was a brake issue but now I'm not so sure. When I inspected the wheel placement it looks as if the wheel is misaligned on the "hub tube". I took a few photos to illustrate the potential problem. But can only post two of them here (2 link limit, not enough reputation).

This is how the caliper aligns with the socket when on the rotor. Not very well at all.
https://onedrive.live.com/redir?resid=5FF9BFDF1E0E64EB%2120369
https://onedrive.live.com/redir?resid=5FF9BFDF1E0E64EB%2120370

The brake worked fine for a year then all of the sudden the front wheel got stuck. If I attach the caliper to the socket the right pad presses firmly against the disc rotor. It looks as if the whole hub has moved a few mm to the right on the "tube". The wheel is not centered in the front fork. The rear wheel IS centered.

Is the front wheel supposed to be centered. If so can I fix the hub alignment myself?

Comment: I can’t see the photos but please check the end caps are on the axle

Answer (score 0):

How much displacement are we talking about.  A mm or two?

I've never heard of the wheel moving along the axle.  Is the 15QR skewer (the axle) tight?  There is a rotatable nut with numbers on the opposite side which you can adjust to move the final angle at which the skewer lever handle sits.

One thing I would try is to remove the caliper completely (two bolts to the fork) and see if the rim and or the rotor wobbles when turned.  Also check to see if the wheel itself is loose and moves "along the axle" or rattles / has loose play.  The front wheel on my Nerve AL 8.9 is centered, as far as I can tell.

It's possible that the caliper position changed during a crash.  There is slop in the two mounting bolts on purpose so that you can center the caliper pads onto the disk.  But before you try that, you should probably make sure the disks aren't warped as well.

Comment: Before making any adjustments on disc brakes, one should always make sure the wheel is properly attached to the frame or fork.  The first step should be to remove the wheel and reattach it (assuring the hub isn't damaged in the process).  Doing any work to align disc brakes before this step is wasted effort if the wheel is not properly attached.